# Retraining a machine learning model

Tags: data

Created a Machine Learning model on some data. Used this model for predicting test data. Model has learnt only from training data. How this model can be retrained as new data come in for prediction. I don't know whether it is true that retraining a model is necessary so that it can predict new data more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a lot of factors:

- Does the function you're learning change overtime ? If you try to detect dogs in pictures, and you already have a good accuracy, then relearning is not necessary. But if you try to detect topics in news streams, then you'll need to update your model regularly.
- Do you have initially enough data ? If you receive a stream of training data, then you should find an algorithm that can be trained in an online manner.
- If you are looking for constantly improving the accuracy, then the more data you feed the better results you'll get. Regularly retraining a new model with the old data + the new ones might be sufficient.

Comment: if data is enough for learning more data could not change the model significantly.  you can understand data is enough or not from "learning curve"

Answer (score 0):

your model should learn, it should not memorize items. So if you made a good model you don't need to worry about the new items.
However, in some cases model may change in time, in these cases, you can relearn the model after a while (with past data those you surely know the answers).

Comment: I would like to know more about relearning a model in python. Are there any documents or links ?

Comment: It's not a method, it's a strategy. after a while that you use your model you decide to make your model better with new data. So you fit your model with new data and maybe you change your modeling parameter. (However, there is a parameter for a model to start to learn from the previous finding but it's not for relearning, rather it use for speed up in learning.) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as 'online learning'.  In summary, yes it's possible, but when re-initialising the model you should also ensure you restore the state of the optimizer, e.g. learning rate/decay and any other parameters it might use.

In Keras you can save checkpoints, i.e. the model, and when you re-load the checkpoints it restores the state of the network at that point, including the optimizer state.

If training the entire network from scratch doesn't take long, you might be just as worthwhile doing a complete re-train with the new/extended dataset.